# Calling onmouseover function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple div's and I have a unique code for each div and whenever a user comes across a specific div I want only that div to be counted.

My problem is if I use onmouseover-html then the function which is triggered is running multiple times.

There are posts which suggest using mouseenter-jquery thing but If I use mouseenter-jquery I don't know how to get the unique code of div's.

I tried onmouseover and server got too busy and failed.

```
$('sample').mouseenter(function(this){ 
   var sample = $("#sample input.sam").val(); 
   document.write(sample);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helping to raise your content quality

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('some-div').mouseenter(function(){ 
    console.log(this); 
    console.log($(this)); 
});
```

Comment: some-div should be dynamically changed when user hover on different divs

Comment: you can listen to all divs and inside the function figure out which one is which div by getting it's id, some attribute or position @NandagiriAkhilesh

Comment: just use $('div').mouseenter.... and on any div that is entered you'll receive an event and you'll have the object of that particular div

Comment: so if some div with id 12345 is mouse overed u say that i can have that div id as an object with in the mouseenter function. Thanks for the suggestion and i need to try it once thanks :)

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('sample').mouseenter(function(this){ 
  var sample = $("#sample input.sam").val(); 
   document.write(sample);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000000;" id="sample">
<input type="hidden" value="1234" class="sam">
heloooooooooo
</div>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: #7B4B4C;" id="dip">
<input type="hidden" value="9845" class="sam">
heloooooooooo
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: do not do function(this) callback receives event not the context in arguments name it e or event... but what did you want to ask? by posting the code? @NandagiriAkhilesh

Comment: the code is not working i want the value of input to be assigned to var sample on mouse enter into any div can u suggest the code

Comment: $('div').mouseenter(function() { var sample = $(this).find('input').val(); document.write(sample) }); this code will listen to every div on the page and on mouse enter it will try to find an input inside the div and give the value of the input. is this what you want?

Comment: Your code really loos simple and clean thanks .yes thats what i want  and i tried your code by replacing it with the previous code i have posted here , i dont know the problem but when i hover my mouse into any of the div nothing happening .

Comment: can you create a fiddle and give a link so i can play with it and give you the working version

Comment: and I think your jquery url is not working.. include first version of jquery here is url: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i included them and saved file as html should save with other extension or what still not working on server :(

Comment: @NandagiriAkhilesh you do not need to include both

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('div').mouseenter(function(e) {
    var sample = $(this).find('input').val();
    alert(sample);
 document.write('sample');
  });</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000000;" id="sample">
    <input type="hidden" value="1234" class="sam"> heloooooooooo
  </div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: #7B4B4C;" id="dip">
    <input type="hidden" value="9845" class="sam"> heloooooooooo
  </div>
</body>

Comment: my entire code is this still its not working can you test it